# virtualbox client performance issues in graphical mode

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I hope this is he right stack exchange to ask this question.

I have a Win10 host running virtualbox 6.0.8. I am running a CentOS 7 client. A default CentOS installation uses a multi-user.target (runlevel 3?). This works fine, however I would like a graphical interface so I changed it to graphical.target (runlevel 5?). I installed the vbox additions to get the mouse integration working correctly.

The problem is that there is a noticeable lag/delay between input devices (both keyboard & mouse) and CentOS responding to that - i.e. a character to show in a shell or a menu item to gain focus.

If I use putty on the host or a remote linux machine using commandline ssh to connect to the client, there is no lag at all.

The host is an i5-4460 with 16GB of RAM. I assigned 6GB of RAM, 2 processors & 128MB video memory to the client. The client is out of the box, other than changing the default runlevel I haven't installed or changed anything.